# Firestore - Reading based on a key having period (.) inside its name

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have run `set()` on some Firestore documents to set a nested key, but with wrong syntax like so:

```
document.set({ 'a.b': true })
```

Now the problem is that instead of creating `{a: {b: true}}`, this has created `{ 'a.b': true}` inside the document.
I want to now read these corrupted documents, but when I do `where('a.b', '===', true)` it assumes `b` to be nested inside `a`.

How can I now run `where()` on a key named `a.b`?

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer in the Firestore's API reference. There is a class called [`FieldPath`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldPath) which can be used to construct a document's field path i.e. key name. The way it constructs a nested field path is by taking multiple parameters in the constructor. So if you just pass one parameter, it would take it as a single key name (even if it has a period inside it).

Eg: `firestore.FieldPath('a.b')`